# How long will the site be beta for?

Tags: discussion, beta

Seems busy here. I'm not sure about quality, seems reasonable, though maybe a bit practical and not enough scholarship.

How long will the site be beta for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for your convenience, here is the stat as of Feb '19

[image]

Maybe some advertisements would push this, since other criteria are excellent. We just need to explain why the Q&A format helps learning and practicing Buddhism.

There is also a demonstration of Writing to graduate: [Writing.SE clamours for graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322781/260800)

Comment: So in that link they're saying that the distinction between beta and non-beta is becoming blurred (though progress toward that is slow, year-long). The biggest differences (between beta and graduated) would be tweaking the appearance of the site (which they scarcely have time/resources for), and moderator elections (which they might do if necessary even if the site were still in beta).

Answer (score 2):

I guess there aren't enough questions per day to graduate -- see http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/45110/buddhism --  there are currently 4 per day, and SE might prefer 10.

The last I read though, many months ago, was that SE no longer has a "graduate or die" policy for beta sites: i.e. a site that doesn't graduate can stay in beta for as long as it remains useful.

Comment: really only 4, that's surprising, cheers. i usually look at trhe bump page, i guess